# urllib.requests.urlopen() causes CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I am trying to familiarize myself with the urllib module in Python 3. 
The code below is not working on my computer but works when I test it on repl.it for some reason.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, I am running python 3.6.5 if that helps.

```
    import urllib.request 
    req = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.pythonprogramming.net') 
    print (req.read())
```

The error I get is

> urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)

I am using a Mac

Comment: You will need to provide the error if you want any help

Comment: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)> This is the error. I am using a Mac